# Amazon EC2 Status Checks: 2/2 checks

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

What, specifically, are the `2/2 checks` that come under the Status Checks column in the AWS EC2 console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWS provides excellent [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html) on pretty much everything they do.

There are two types of status checks: system status checks and instance status checks.

**System Status Checks**

Monitor the AWS systems on which your instance runs. These checks detect underlying problems with your instance that require AWS involvement to repair. When a system status check fails, you can choose to wait for AWS to fix the issue, or you can resolve it yourself. For instances backed by Amazon EBS, you can stop and start the instance yourself, which migrates it to a new host computer. For instances backed by instance store, you can terminate and replace the instance.

The following are examples of problems that can cause system status checks to fail:

- Loss of network connectivity
- Loss of system power
- Software issues on the physical host
- Hardware issues on the physical host that impact network reachability

**Instance Status Checks**

Monitor the software and network configuration of your individual instance. These checks detect problems that require your involvement to repair. When an instance status check fails, typically you will need to address the problem yourself (for example, by rebooting the instance or by making instance configuration changes).

The following are examples of problems that can cause instance status checks to fail:

- Failed system status checks
- Incorrect networking or startup configuration
- Exhausted memory
- Corrupted file system
- Incompatible kernel

Comment: Tim - thanks - very helpful. Yes, their docs are good but suffer from the same problem as Apple's. 1. vast reams of information that take ages to wade through. 2. miles away from the issue (e.g. why don't they have a menu item that pops up over the item which links to the docs?).

Comment: Contextual help would be useful, but may make the interface even easier. I knew the general answer, but I googled "AWS instance status checks" to find the reference for you.